# class diagram for accessing & storing logs

Tags: php, uml, design-patterns

I need to log search parameter and then want to access them.

[image]

1. search class : will perform search  based on searchParams class (having searched parameters)
2. searchLogger : perform search logging and one of them will be search performed by user.
3. searchParam : class to set search parameters from user search or from logger.

**DOUBTS:**
search logger should be just to log. but i am accessing this as well(retrieve logs based on ids) .how should i handle this ?? should i create one more class ??

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean u r accessing the logger as well?

If you mean you ACCESS  the logger object to perform log operation that is fine.

You should not reinvent the wheel and just use:

- an existing logging framework like [log4NET](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [nlog](http://nlog-project.org/) etc.
- and possibly write a wrapper class around logging framework you decide to use

hope this helps.

Comment: I need to retrieve log based on primary key.
i m looking for a class diagram to capture this flow